# What is a Hanging Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Hanging Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Hanging Words™ | Not Hanging Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| GLOW | SHINE |
| GUN | TASER |
| TULIP | ROSE |
| BEACH | SHORE |
| WALK | STRIDE |
| ECZEMA | RASH |
| MUD | DIRT |
| SECRET | HIDDEN |
| PIG | HORSE |
| ALERT | TIRED |
| BAGGINS | SHIRE |
| FOX | ROOSTER |
| JOY | SADNESS |
| QUICHE | TART |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Hanging Words™,Not Hanging Words™
GLOW,SHINE
GUN,TASER
TULIP,ROSE
BEACH,SHORE
WALK,STRIDE
ECZEMA,RASH
MUD,DIRT
SECRET,HIDDEN
PIG,HORSE
ALERT,TIRED
BAGGINS,SHIRE
FOX,ROOSTER
JOY,SADNESS
QUICHE,TART
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Hanging Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Hanging Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

An aside: It might be more accurate to flip the columns and call them 'Not-Hanging Words' and 'Not Not-Hanging Words', given the rule determining them

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A word is hanging if

> it contains a letter not in ETAIONSHRD, the [ten most common English letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:English_letter_frequency_(frequency).svg)

The names comes from

> the word game [hangman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game)), where a player must guess all the letters in a word within a certain number of guesses. If they don't get it within that number, the man is "hanged". A common strategy is to guess common letters first, so these are words that cause a hanging with 10 guesses of the most common letters.

Comment: Exactly right, well done!

Answer (score 3):

This is a kinda non-answer answer, but so far as the provided lists go it seems that a word is Hanging if and only if

> it contains one of the letters BCGKLMUWZ.

Obviously this is not a satisfactory answer for three reasons:

> it doesn't give any insight into what actual difference is intended; there may be Hanging Words we haven't seen that don't contain any of those letters; there may be Not Hanging Words we haven't seen that do contain some of them.

But I will hazard a guess that

> some answer of the form "a word is Hanging if and only if it contains one of the following set of letters: ..." is in fact correct (though a *sufficiently insightful* answer should also explain why that set of letters)

in which case

> the correct set of letters must not include any of ADEHINOPRST (because those are all found in Not Hanging Words); it may also include some or all of FJQXY (which are not present in either list in the question).

And, slightly less trivially,

> it must include C (because of SECRET), G (because of PIG), L (because of ALERT), and either M or U (because of MUD). These suffice to explain all the other listed Hanging Words.

So, to summarize:

> Assuming that an answer of the given form correctly distinguishes Hanging from Not Hanging, the set of Hanging letters *does* include C, G, L, and either M or U; it *may* include the other of M,U as well as some or all of BFJKQWXYZ; it *must not* include any of ADEHINOPRST.

Comment: All correct observations thus far, and it seems that I made a mistake with one non-hanging word (sheep). Sorry!